# Android Studio 1.0.2 with JUnit4 Tests

Tags: android, junit, android-studio, junit4

I'm currently using Android Studio version 1.0.2. I've created a couple of classes and have had Android Studio generate some JUnit 4 test skeletons for me. When I was generating these tests, it informed me that the JUnit4 library wasn't found in the module. There was a button that said 'Fix' so I clicked that and it allowed me to create a new test. I've also checked git and it doesn't seem like it altered any other files.

[image: Create Test JUnit4 library not found]

I seem to have run into an error when trying to run these tests.

Here is what my test looks

```
package com.example.username.shapes;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.ExpectedException;

public class PointTest {
    @Rule
    ExpectedException expectedException = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void testGimmie() throws Exception {
        assertEquals(123456, Point.gimmie(55));

        expectedException.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);
        Point.gimmie(-1);
    }
}
```

I had some error where it couldn't resolve symbol 'junit'. Following this I had a search around and found some previous questions about this but for versions of Android Studio prior to 1.0. I ended up adding `androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'` to my app build file.

When I try to run tests I get an error saying

> Error:(13, 9) error: cannot find symbol method assertEquals(int,int)

I tried commenting that line out and running the tests but then I get this error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebugTest'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
> >       C:\Users\username\Downloads\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140624\sdk\build-tools\21.1.1\dx.bat
> >     --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ProjectName\app\build\intermediates\dex\test\debug
> >     --input-list=C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ProjectName\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\test\debug\inputList.txt
> >     Error Code:   2 Output:   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
> >       com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
> >     Lorg/hamcrest/Description;        at
> >     com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
> >           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
> >           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
> >           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
> >           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)         at
> >     com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
> >           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:302)      at
> >     com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:245)      at
> >     com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)         at
> >     com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

Is there a solution for this that someone can point me to or describe what steps to take? I'm also curious to know if there's another way that I should be adding the junit4 library.

Comment: i had this same issue. There was some overlap between junit and hamcrest. Remove the hamcrest and it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue and got around it by excluding the `hamcrest-core` module from junit-4x.

```
androidTestCompile('junit:junit:4.10') {
    exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
}
androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'
```

Answer (score -3):

I have meet the same problem.
I solved by the follow way：

1. Open the window :Build Variants
2. In "Test Artfact", select "Unit Tests"
3. Then, you can create the tests by your way.

[image]
[image]